# Add Quotes to Convert JSON to POJO

Tags: java, android, json, pojo

I wanted to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert my JSON response to Java, however the JSON I am viewing does not have quotes, therefore I cannot use this site. Any ideas on how I can generate the JSON with quotes to take advantage of this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class addQuotes{
    String dir = "enter file location here";
    File quotes = new File(dir);

private String readFile(){
    String q = "";

    try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(dir)){
        int s = (int) quotes.length();
        byte[] r = new byte[s];
        fin.read(r);
        q = new String(r);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return q;
}

private void writeFile(FileOutputStream fos, String output) throws IOException{
    byte[] data = output.getBytes();
    fos.write(data);
}

public addQuotes() {
    String add = readFile().replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\"$1\"");
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos =  new FileOutputStream(dir);
        writeFile(fos, add);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution was not working properly with values that have hyphens and/or spaces.
Here is my take:

```
    String json = json.replaceAll(", ", ","); // #LC2759 
    int n = json.length(); // leetcode 2759
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        char c = json.charAt(i);
        if(c == ':'){
            // add closing quote for key; 
            result.append("\":");
            if(json.charAt(i+1) != '{' && json.charAt(i+1) != '[')// add opening quote for value 
                result.append("\"");
            if(json.charAt(i+1) == '}' || json.charAt(i+1) == ']' || json.charAt(i+1) == ',')// value empty
                result.append("\"");
            continue;
        }
        
        if(c == '{' || c == '[' && (json.charAt(i+1) != '{' && json.charAt(i+1) != '[')){
            // add opening bracket and then opening quote for key
            result.append(c); 
            result.append("\"");
        }
        else if(i < n-1 && (json.charAt(i+1) == ',' || json.charAt(i+1) == ']' || json.charAt(i+1) == '}') && c != ']' && c != '}'){
            // add closing quote for value
            result.append(c); 
            result.append("\"");
        }
        else if(c == ',' && json.charAt(i+1) != '{' && json.charAt(i+1) != '[')
            result.append(",\"");
        else result.append(c); 
        
        
    }
```